# How to check if file is newer than 15 min in for loop

Tags: mysql, bash, for-loop

I'm looking to process files that have been modified within 15 minutes, ignoring the rest. I want to do this in a for loop, like:

```
for f in *; do
    if test 'find $f -mtime -0h15m'
    then
        mysql -e "load data local infile '"$f"' 
                  into table "$MYSQL_TABLE" 
                  fields terminated by '\t' 
                  lines terminated by '\n' 
                  ignore 1 lines" -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS $MYSQL_DB --local-infile
    fi
done
```

When I run the above, all files are imported, even those older than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, the argument to `-mtime` is a number of days, not minutes, you need to use `--mmin` to specify a the difference in minutes.

Second, you're using the wrong type of quotes. To substitute the result of a string into a command, you have to use backticks or `$()`. Since quotes just return a literal string, they don't execute the command.

You should also quote it to prevent problems if the filename has spaces or other special characters.

So it should be:

```
if test "$(find "$f" -mmin -15)"
then
```

Comment: oh I missed that quote thing!

Comment: this worked like a charm, thanks @Barmar! (and thanks JFF for your responses)

Answer (score 1):

`-mtime` accepts only a given number of days (well, for versions I know of!)

use the `-mmin` option of `find`, perfectly suited for what you want:

```
if test `find $f -mmin -15`
```

Comment: hmm... that still didn't work. the files from yesterday were still imported with that approach. are there other issues with my script above?

Comment: yes, see Barmar answer (or my edit with backquotes). I answered too quickly I missed the 2nd problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `find` once for each file is wasteful; call it once to find the matching files.

```
cmd="load data local infile '{}'
into table $MYSQL_TABLE
fields terminated by '\t'
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines"

find . -mmin -15 -exec mysql -e "$cmd" -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS $MYSQL_DB --local-infile \;
```